# MySql CREATE EVENT Error

Tags: mysql, events

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END$$ DELIMITER' at line 4

```
CREATE EVENT event_1 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY DO BEGIN 
UPDATE 
    sonice_User 
SET 
    update_chance = "1"; END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     CREATE EVENT event_1 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK 
     STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
     DO 
     UPDATE   sonice_User 
     SET update_chance = "1";
```

Answer (score 3):

use below code:

```
 Delimiter $$
 CREATE EVENT event_1 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK 
     STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
     DO 
     BEGIN
     UPDATE   sonice_User 
     SET update_chance = "1";
     END $$
 Delimiter ;
```

Comment: no , it's still wrong.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER;' at line 1